# How can I get declared filesize and total file size from APK file?

Tags: python, apk

this is my first question on stackoverflow, a little nervous? :)

While I'm extracting classes information from APK file via DalvikFormat(I used 'get_dex', 'get_classes' method), getting warning message like below.

```
Declared filesize (9764) is smaller than total file size (9768). Was something appended to the file? Trying to parse it anyways.
AXML file has an unusual resource type! Malware likes to to such stuff to anti androguard! But we try to parse it anyways. Resource Type: 0x0000
```

I want to know what is meaning of declared file size and total file size, and want to know how to get them.
Additionally, I got below answer from chatGPT to get total file size. 
Also please check whether below code is correct or not to get total file size.

```
total_file_size = os.path.getsize(apk_file)

with zipfile.ZipFile(benign_path[10], 'r') as apk_zip:
    # Get the info of the APK file itself
    apk_info = apk_zip.getinfo(benign_path[0])

    # Get the declared file size
    declared_size = apk_info.file_size
```

I tried above code to get declared file size, but it is not working, I'm facing keyerror.
Even I have no confidence whether it is correct or not.

FYI, the reason why I want to know this,
only some malware apk show me this warning. 
So I want to do EDA via file size data.

Comment: Show the entire error.  Don't make us guess.

Comment: You forgot to mention that this whole question Androguard specific. The message you have posted is about AXML files and their internal size. https://github.com/androguard/androguard/blob/bd85695da888f3d66d6f8abd1c0bde31b348e6d0/androguard/core/axml/__init__.py#L425 The chatGPT code is just about regular ZIP files and thus totally useless to understand what Androguard mentiones in the message. Better read the Androguard source code to understand what is message means.